# Can PowerShell Compare-Object do a binary compare?

Tags: powershell

These two files are clearly different. But `Compare-Object` finds no difference. The first file has a Unicode BOM. Is there any way to get `Compare-Object` to identify that they are different?

```
PS C:\Temp> dir file*

    Directory: C:\Temp

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2021-06-01    14:38         163673 file1.txt
-a---          2021-03-18    17:08         163670 file2.txt

PS C:\Temp> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file2.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file2.txt)
PS C:\Temp> Format-Hex -Path .\file1.txt | Select-Object -First 1

   Label: C:\Temp\file1.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 ***EF BB BF*** 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E ï»¿<?xml version

PS C:\Temp> Format-Hex -Path .\file2.txt | Select-Object -First 1

   Label: C:\Temp\file2.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31 <?xml version="1

PS C:\Temp> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.1.3
```

Comment: I get the same results in PS5.1. You could do a comparison between the bytes as a workaround but I guess that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The two *files* are different, but the *strings* produced by `Get-Content` are identical.

Use the `-Encoding` parameter to make `Get-Content` read the raw byte values:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content .\file2.txt -Encoding Byte) (Get-Content .\file1.txt -Encoding Byte)
```

---

You might find `Get-FileHash` more efficient for detecting byte-level equality of two (or more) files:

```
PS ~> Get-FileHash *.txt
    
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          F1945CD6C19E56B3C1C78943EF5EC18116907A4CA1EFC40A57D48AB1DB7ADFC5       C:\path\to\file1.txt
SHA256          E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855       C:\path\to\file2.txt
```

Comment: `Byte` is not a valid encoding.

Comment: `Get-Content: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Encoding'. 'Byte' is not a supported encoding name.`

Comment: @lit: Unfortunately, `-Encoding Byte` was removed from PowerShell (Core) v6+ in favor of the new `-AsByteStream` switch - a frivolous breaking change discussed in [GitHub issue #7986](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7986)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Get-Content -AsByteStream` will indicate differences.

```
PS C:\Temp> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file1.txt -AsByteStream) `
    -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file2.txt -AsByteStream)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
        239 <=
        187 <=
        191 <=

PS C:\Temp> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file1.txt -AsByteStream) `
    -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file1.txt -AsByteStream))
True
PS C:\Temp> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file1.txt -AsByteStream) `
    -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path .\file2.txt -AsByteStream))
False
```

Comment: Unfortunately for huge files this just eats a tonne of RAM (instead of doing what you would think it should; stream through both files until it hits the first differing byte)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Yes, `Compare-Object` *can* do a binary compare.

BUT: It's hopelessly slow and will crash on large files.

Better to use a buffered approach written by Kees Bakker. Or, if you prefer a native function, `FC`, which is slower, but not terribly slow for a small job.

See a comparison of all those methods in [*Speed of binary file comparisons in PowerShell*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76895989/speed-of-binary-file-comparisons-in-powershell/)